# How can I peg an external to a specific revision using SVN command line

Tags: svn, revision

I am using Torsoise SVN as a version control at work. We have a model that has a couple of externals attached with it, each typically being pegged to a certain revision. I need to have a code that when run, checks the externals for a specified location, determines whether they are currently pegged or not, then if there are any externals that aren't pegged, peg them at the revision number that is currently HEAD. I have already figured out how to use 'propget' to determine if the externals are pegged and if so what revision number. Now what I am having trouble figuring out is how to use the command line to peg the other unpegged externals to a revision number I choose. There seems to be some way to do this with 'propset' according to the SVN command line help, but I apparently cannot get the syntax right and have no clue what is wrong with it. To help make it a little more clear, here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Lets say my model is locally at "C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\Test\ProdBranches\1.3.x\Controller" with a SVN URL of "https://example.com/svn/Test/ProdBranches/1.3.x/Controller".

Controller has two externals: CAN and Lib

Their local paths are: CAN - "C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\VCM_Library\trunk\CAN"  &  Lib - "C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\VCM_Library\trunk\Simulink"

Their SVN URLs are: CAN - "https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/CAN"  &  Lib - "https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/Simulink"

I can run the command "svn propget svn:externals -R C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\Test\ProdBranches\1.3.x\Controller" and get the response "Documents\2021\Test\ProdBranches\1.3.x\Controller - https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/CAN@504 CAN
https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/Simulink Lib"

So I can see that CAN is pegged at 504. Now I want to peg Lib to 579. How can I do that?

Here is what happened when I tried svn propset. I did propdel to remove the externals and this is how I tried to add CAN back at revision 504:

C:\Users\me>svn ps svn:externals -r504 https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/CAN@504 C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\Test\ProdBranches\1.3.x\Controller

svn: E205000: Try 'svn help propset' for more information
svn: E205000: Cannot specify revision for setting versioned property 'svn:externals'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 (slightly) different ways to go:

1. Do it in one command `svn propedit` (see [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propedit.html) for details)

Pro: single command
Contra: pure interactive mode

2. Use pair `svn propdel` + `svn propset`

Pro: can be easy automated
Contra: two commands

Comment: I tried that and the propdel worked but I still cannot get propset to. See edited post

Comment: @HunterLazenby - you **must not use** operative revision for defined *versioned property* (`--revprop --rev N` used only for revision properties)

Comment: which part of what I wrote is using the operative revision? I am not exactly sure what changes to make

Comment: @HunterLazenby - `svn ps`, obviously. Write just `svn ps svn:externals  https://example.com/svn/VCM_Library/trunk/CAN@504 C:\Users\me\Documents\2021\Test\ProdBranches\1.3.x\Controller` and all will be OK

Answer (score 0):

This begs the question of why isn't this actually in the tool --peg-externals is mad using HEAD rather than the current revision